# Error when creating table using NCHAR datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am creating a simple table but there is an error:

```
[Error] Execution (23: 29): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I am not missing any parenthesis. This errors refers to the line with

```
DEPARTMENTURL   NCHAR(10 BYTE),
```

I was able to create the table removing this line, I'm not sure what is the issue. I am using TOAD and I've restarted it.

Please see code below:

```
  CREATE TABLE HR.DEPARTMENT(
    DEPARTMENTID    NUMBER(10),
    NAME            NUMBER(10),
    ABBREVIATION    NUMBER(10),
    URL             VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    DEPARTMENTURL   NCHAR(10 BYTE),
    BANNERDEPTCODE  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    UPAYURL         TIMESTAMP
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 columns can **only** be specified in characters, never in bytes, and you can only specify the length (in characters), you can't even use the word CHAR in the length specification.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1825

To understand the error message, put yourself in the parser's shoes (and remember that parsers, optimizers etc. are not "intelligent" beings). The parser sees NCHAR, so it knows that it should see the length next. It sees the opening parenthesis, the number 10, and then another token that is not the closing parenthesis, which is the **only** valid "next token" at that point. Whence the error message.